# difference between MPI_Send() and MPI_Ssend()?

Tags: ipc, mpi, openmpi

I know `MPI_Send()` is a blocking call ,which waits until it is safe to modify the application buffer for reuse. For making the send call synchronous(there should be a handshake with the receiver) , we need to use `MPI_Ssend()` .
I want to know the difference between the two. Suppose i need to send fix amount of Bytes among the processes , which one is supposed to take longer time ?
With me the code works well the MPI_Send() call but waiting indefinitely for MPI_Ssend().
What could be the possible reasons ?

And the most important thing is , i am pretty sure the data is being received at the receiving process when using `MPI_Send()` ,so this inference leads nothing in favor to wait for the handshake when using `MPI_Ssend()` .

Or i can make a conclusion : with `MPI_Send()` you can send data to the self process but can't using `MPI_Ssend()` ?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

There is a small but important difference between the two (you can find it in the [MPI 3.0 Standard](http://mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-3.0/mpi30-report.pdf#section.3.4) document in Section 3.4). With a regular `MPI_SEND`, the implementation will return to the application when the buffer is available for reuse. This *could* be before the receiving process has actually posted the receive. For instance, it could be when a small message has been copied into an internal buffer and the application buffer is no longer needed. However, for large messages that may not be buffered internally, the call may not return until enough of the message has been sent to the remote process that the buffer is no longer needed.

The difference between this and `MPI_SSEND` is that the latter will *always* wait until the receive has been posted on the receiving end. Even if the message is small and can be buffered internally, it will still wait until the message has started to be received on the other side.

`MPI_SSEND` is a way of ensuring that both processes have reached a certain point in their execution without having to do an `MPI_BARRIER`, for instance. If your application is sending and receiving to and from the same rank, it's not safe to do either `MPI_SEND` OR `MPI_SSEND`, as either one *could* block indefinitely. Instead, you should use `MPI_ISEND` and `MPI_IRECV` so that the calls will return immediately and the actual send/receive can be done at the same time (in the call to `MPI_WAITALL`).

Comment: And the most important thing is , i am pretty sure the data is being received at the receiving process when using MPI_Send() ,so this inference leads nothing in favor to wait for the handshake when using MPI_Ssend() . my code works fine with MPI_Send() but waiting indefinitely with MPI_Ssend() .Can you think of any possible reasons  ?

Comment: It would entirely depend on your code. If for some reason your code doesn't reach the matching call to `MPI_RECV` without progression from the `MPI_SEND` for some reason, that could cause the deadlock, but there's no way to tell without seeing the code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17820445/openmpi-hello-world-on-cluster can you please answer that ?